# Limit on Interaction Terms in Regression

Tags: regression, interaction, econometrics

How many two-way interaction terms can you include in a regression model? Is there any consequences to coefficient interpretations or clarity of model?

i.e. $$Y = b_0 + b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + b_3X_3 + b_4X_4 + b_4X_1X_2 +
          b_5X_1X_3 + b_6X_1X_4$$

Comment: It depends. The consequences could be great if you interact a bunch of ‘multi-valued’ categorical predictors, resulting in too many additive and multiplicative effects on the right-hand side of your equation.

Comment: Ok would if all they were all dummy variables i.e. X1 was 'female' and the X2-4 were levels of education with Y being say income?

Comment: Hi @Econowombat  Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to include the information in your comment.

Comment: I also edited your formula for formatting issues, please check that it is correct and fix it if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing limiting you is the degrees of freedom i.e. the number of rows you have in your data (and also how many independent variables you have to begin with). In econometrics, you should include all variables that affect the dependent variable to avoid omitted variable bias.

For the coefficient interpretation, if the model is for example [image: eq], then sales is defined as a linear relationship of tv advertising and newspaper advertising plus the combined effect of both variables. When tv advertising is increased, it is assumed to increase the sales in two ways, i.e. high tv advertising and high newspaper advertising increases the sales more than either one separately.

The clarity of the model might suffer as in any situation where you add lots of predictors. In addition to this you cannot look at just the coefficient of a single variable if that specific variable is also included in an interaction, instead you have to look at both the coefficient of the variable and the coefficient of the interaction.

Comment: I should add, we *should* include (possibly all) variables that affect the dependent variable, but they should also be *correlated* with the independent variable(s) of interest.